# Ubuntu でマイクだけを無効にしたい

Tags: ubuntu

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf に backlist snd_hda_intel を入れて再起動しましたが、スピーカーとマイクが無効になってしまいます。
こういう問題が結構あるはずなんだけど見つからない。
どうすればいけるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ドライバ snd_hda_intel 自体を無効にすると入力(マイク)、出力(スピーカー)とも無効になるのでしょう。
GNOME などのデスクトップ環境ならば、パネルから入出力それぞれの音量やミュートができませんでしょうか？
あるいは、オーディオ管理プログラムが PulseAudio ならば、
PulseAudio 音量調節 (pavucontrol) などの GUI アプリや、pactl, pacmd などのコマンドで。